# What is the performance cost of calculating values in onDraw vs reading them from memory when drawing on android canvas?

Tags: java, android-activity, android-canvas, android-view

When I optimize my android app is it worth it to move all calculations from `onDraw()` to for ex.`onSurfaceChanged()` and store calculated values?
For example I got:

```
onDraw(...){
...
canvas.drawText(text,
                    mBounds.left+ mLineXOffset,
                    mBounds.top + mLineYOffset,
                    mTextPaint);
```

Will it be much difference in terms in battery drain if I pre calculate all absolute values in `onSurfaceChanged()`?

Edit: in this case onDraw is probably called few times a second and app is always "screen on".

Comment: Although I'm not deeply familiar with Android in particular, I'm pretty sure that the answer will be "that depends...". But I'm also pretty sure that a few additions (even hundreds of them per draw call) will not affect the battery lifetime. Keeping and fetching data in memory isn't free either.

Comment: @Marco13 I'm less worried about adding  int/float values. In a lot of places I'm calling bitmap methods like `mBitmap.getWidth()/0,7' etc. I'm writing a watch face so I want do do everything I can to minimize battery drain.